# New code snippet causes error on submit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

StackOverflow's editor seem to have changed, or to be more precise, the settings for the snippet editor that allow to run code in questions/answers have changed. The snippets are now executed in a sandbox mode that doesn't allow the submission of forms (something that was possible before), receiving the following message in Chrome:

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

This affects all the snippets that use the `submit` event in forms (even the ones in which `preventDefault` prevents submission) and they have stopped working. Example of an [answer in StackOverflow in Spanish affected by this](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14314/250).

Is this a known issue? What should we do with the posts that are affected by this?

Comment: Also reported on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344191/why-is-form-submit-disabled-in-stack-snippets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just added the `allow-forms` token to the snippet's [`iframe's sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute, so submission is now possible:

```html
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Since we already allow your arbitrary script, allowing form submission didn't seem to add any new capabilities that would cause more security concerns.